# Loading csv-files in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

In R I have created two datasets which I have saved as csv-files by

```
liste <-write.csv(liste, file="/home/.../liste.csv", row.names=FALSE)
    data <- write.csv(data, file="/home/.../data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

I now want to open these csv files in SparkR. So I type

```
liste <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/.../liste.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", delimiter= "\t")

data <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/.../data.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", delimiter= "\t")
```

It turns out that the one dataset 'liste' is loaded successfully in SparkR, however, 'data' cannot be loaded for some strange reasons.

'liste' is just a vector of numbers in R whereas 'data' is a data.frame I have loaded in R and removed some parts of the data.frame. SparkR gives me this error-message:

> Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE

Comment: The data-set 'liste' can be loaded succesfully in sparkR. In R 'liste' is a vector 2,3,4,6,9,... But 'data' is a csv-file I have loaded in R and make some changes to. I save it as a csv-file and then try to load it in SparkR which I cant do.

Comment: The csv-file I loaded in R was about 2GB. I simply maked a few changes and saved it as  new csv-file called 'data' but this csv-file is only about  33 KB which is small. I found this very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liste is a local list which can be written with write.csv, data is a SparkR DataFrame which can't be written with write.csv: it only writes its pointer, not the DataFrame. That's why it only is 33 kb

Comment: Thanks for the response. How could I then save it so I can load it in sparkR and threat it like a DataFrame ?

Comment: I am able to save it to parquet: write.df(data,"data".json","parquet","overwrite") or saveAsParquetFile(data, "data") and later you can read the parquet file.